# how to upload images to S3 from android

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I try to upload images to aws s3 from android.

```
File fileToUpload = new File("/DCIM/Camera/20170226_215252.jpg");
```

And error is

02-28 01:58:43.471 25002-25470/app.s3amazon W/System.err: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /DCIM/Camera/20170226_215252.jpg

This directory is in my phone.
How should I write images' directory?

Answer (score 2):

> This directory is in my phone

No, it is not. What *might* exist is:

```
File fileToUpload=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera/20170226_215252.jpg"));
```

This will point somewhere else, as your device's filesystem does not have a root `/DCIM/` directory.

Note that you also need to hold either the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to be able to work with this file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one
    "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20170226_215252.jpg"